# Como fazer Web Publish de aplicações aninhadas para o IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que consiste num portal e uma interface de administração.

No Visual Studio eu tenho dois projetos ASP.NET, onde um é o Portal e o outro é a interface de administração.

No meu IIS local eu tenho uma aplicação chamada **PortalWeb** e dentro desta aplicação tenho uma (sub-)aplicação chamada **PortalAdmin**. Desta forma, só é necessário ignorar a rota **/Admin** na aplicação principal (**PortalWeb**) e sempre que eu acesso o endereço da aplicação **/Admin** é chamada a aplicação **PortalAdmin**.

Pra ilustrar, as aplicações no IIS ficam dessa forma

[image: Portal a Portal.Admin no IIS]

Eu quero que, no meu servidor, as aplicações fiquem exatamente dessa maneira. Mas quero fazer isso usando o WebPublish do IIS. Atualmente, eu consigo enviar a aplicação pai (**Portal**) via WebPublish, mas na aplicação **Admin** não existe a opção de configurá-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que a solução é mais simples do que você imagina...

Primeiro, gere um **profile** do **Web Deploy** do sistema **Portal**.

Após isso, deve ser gerado um arquivo parecido com esse (editado no Sublime Text).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<publishData>
  <publishProfile
    publishUrl="https://SERVER/msdeploy.axd"
    msdeploySite="PATH"
    destinationAppUrl="URL_OPEN"
    mySQLDBConnectionString=""
    SQLServerDBConnectionString=""
    profileName="Default Settings"
    publishMethod="MSDeploy"
    userName="USER" />
</publishData>
```

Neste arquivo que é um dos locais para fazer **a mágica**. Onde está o `msdeploySite`, altere o valor para **Portal/Admin** (endereço do Porta mais o sufixo de sua Sub Application, em seu caso **/Admin**).

Isso também pode ser feito na hora de importar o profile ou publicar o sistema, basta adicionar o da Sub Application neste lugar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isto, basta publicar normalmente.

> Só tome cuidado para não dar um **override** na Sub Application ao publicar o Portal. Em resumo, não exclua os arquivos que não pertencerem ao Portal.

Para quem não sabe como configurar o **Web Deploy**, [veja este tutorial.](https://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy)