# Como por um site para teste funcionando no mesmo servidor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho o site da minha empresa, e queria atribuir um outro projeto para teste sem precisar de um outro servidor. Seria basicamente assim:

www.meusite.com/projetoteste/pagina1.cshtml ou seja, dentro da pasta de projeto rodar o projeto em desenvolvimento.

Tentei a possibilidade de fazer aquele procedimento de `ADD > Existing Web Site...`
mas não rolou

Comment: Relacionada [Como fazer Web Publish de aplicações aninhadas para o IIS?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178722/20615)

Comment: Você quer criar um site em paralelo ou um site dentro de um site.
Por exemplo: `www.meusite.com/pagina1.cshtm` e `www.meusiteteste.com/pagina1.cshtm` no mesmo servidor.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como fazer Web Publish de aplicações aninhadas para o IIS?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178722/como-fazer-web-publish-de-aplica%c3%a7%c3%b5es-aninhadas-para-o-iis)

Answer (score 0):

Crie como diretório virtual. Um diretório virtual aparece aos navegadores dos usuários de seu site como se estivesse no diretório raiz do servidor Web.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb763173.aspx